# How to preload images for Foundation's Orbit image slider?

Tags: visibility, zurb-foundation, preloading, image-preloader, orbit

Using Zurb's Foundation 4.1.5 (latest version), the [Orbit image slider](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html) works great. Unfortunately it looks really for the first couple of seconds where all the images appear as a giant bulleted list. Then the JavaScript kicks in and it all is beautiful.

How do I avoid the initial ugliness? Can I preload the images? Can I have everything with `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` until it's ready?

Answer (score 5):

Per [Foundation documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html)

> We've cleaned up how Orbit initializes by adding a wrapper feature
>   that stops the ugly flash of unstyled content. Here's the markup
>   needed:
>
> To add the preloader, simply include a div class="preloader" right
>   inside the wrapper, like so:

```
<div class="slideshow-wrapper">
      <div class="preloader"></div>
      <ul data-orbit>
        <!-- Orbit slides -->
      </ul>
    </div>
```

**Update Tested:** 
Tested with Foundation **4.2.1** http://foundation.zurb.com/download.php

Used Fiddler to throttle download speeds http://fiddler2.com/

Comment: Yes man But You need to try it by your self to know is it working as supposed or not
Thanks for response :)

Comment: Tested it using version 4.2.1 with Fiddler to throttle the connection speed. It worked just fine.